# My android app after installing on android phone says "app isn't install"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.bytes2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".myMainScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.tutorial.CLEARSCREEN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Area_search" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="standard">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.area" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".pinsearch" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.pin" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".categorysearch" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.catagory" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.login" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Register_user" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.catagory" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Admin_page" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Admin" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Add_Restaurant"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Delete_Restaurant"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Name_search"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Aboutus"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Contactus"></activity>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">8Bytes</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="Name">Name</string>
<string name="catagory">Category</string>
<string name="area">Area</string>

<string-array name="items">
    <item>Name Search</item>
    <item>Area Search</item>
    <item>Catagory Search</item>

  <!--   <item>Login</item>
    <item>Register</item> -->

    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Contact Us!</item>
    <item>About</item>
</string-array>

<string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

<color name="Grey">#757575</color>

<string-array name="Area_array">
    <item>Cooke Town</item>
    <item>OMBR</item>
    <item>Banaswadi</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="Category_array">
    <item>North Indian</item>
    <item>South Indian</item>
    <item>Chinies</item>
    <item>Thai</item>
    <item>Italian</item>
</string-array>

<!--
 <string-array name="Name_array">
     <item >McDonald</item>
     <item >PizzaHut</item>
     <item >Dominos</item>
    <item>Tamarind</item>
    <item>Saffron</item>
    <item>Delicias</item>
 </string-array>
-->

<string name="title_activity_add__reastarunt">Add_Reastarunt</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

I have developed this aap with a lot of pain for my semester, and finally made it worked on an emulator but when I try ti reopen the app on an emulator (which is now installed on emulator) it shows an error toast message "app isn't installed" and same happened when i installed the app on an android phone when I installed it got a message app is installed but when I try to open it from the app list it displays the same toast message "app isn't installed" can anyone please help me with this one? :(
22.47
02-11-2015

I'm putting up the String.xml as well

Comment: What's your phone's OS version? Your minSdkVersion is set to 17 so the phone has to be running Android 4.2+ to install it.

Comment: The app is getting installed but when I tap to open it shows the msg "app isn't installed" and I'm trying to run this one on emulator with the API level 17.

Comment: But you said "but when I installed the app on an android phone it says "app isn't installed"", so is it an emulator or a phone?

Comment: Okay my bad I apologize, The problem is after running it on emulator it works fine but when I tap on the icon in app list it shows a toast message "app isn't installed" and when i install it on an android phone it installs but when i try to open it same toast msg  "app isn't installed"...

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer...

Actually there are many reasons the one that was affecting my app was
in AndroidMainfest.Xml file

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

```
    the problem was with this line 
 android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
```

I deleted this and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```